# no affect on cells after formatting - text to numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I've been trying to change the format of an Excel column from text to a number format, but it seems that the format doesn't have any effect on the cells.
I've tried three different ways to do that:

1. Home > Number > then I changed the format from there.
2. Right click > format cells > Number.
3. Data > text to columns > I changed the format to general, after that I used one of the above methods.

Nothing seems to work! The format changes but there is no effect on the cells.

When I tried to work with this Excel file on another PC it worked fine! It seems that there is a problem with my Excel / PC settings.

can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the values are not preceded by `'`. This forces Excel to read this as text.

[image: Formatted as text]

2. Create a column beside the column, and enter `=A1*1`, where `A1` is the reference to the cell beside the column.

[image: Text to number]